# how to close a flat file in DataFlex 3.2

Tags: dataflex

In DataFlex 3.2, I've opened a ASCII file for output, and populated it with data.
When I quit the program, the output file is closed and is accessible by 3rd party software. There has to be a way to close the output file without quitting my DataFlex program, but I can't find a "close" command or similar.

How can I close a file opened for output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close files with the command close_output